# WebDriverException: Service U:/Scraping/chromedriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1 while working with Chrome and Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to get the webdriver to work with Python in Chrome at work, but can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong, despite troubleshooting for most of the day.

I've unzipped chromedriver to the folder I'm working in. I've tried using the `executable_path` argument with chromedriver. I've tried updating the options within chromedriver to direct to the Chrome.exe file.

Code is below. Pretty straightforward. 'url' has an address from earlier in the code that I'm not including here - the script doesn't even make it that far anyways.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'U:/Scraping/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
```

And the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-67-db2ce2aa7cdf>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('U:/Scraping/Project.py', wdir='U:/Scraping')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "U:/Scraping/Project.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'U:/Scraping/chromedriver.exe')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)

WebDriverException: Service U:/Scraping/chromedriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Comment: Show your code.  What language?  What versions?  Make changes to your original post, please.

Comment: Truncating the error trace logs makes debugging tougher. Update the question with error stack trace either from _GeckoDriver_ or _ChromeDriver_ perspective and edit the question to limit it to a specific _WebDriver_ variant

Comment: I would echo the other comments, but you might consider updating your chromedriver if you haven't recently: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies, but I'm still not getting it to work. I've ran it with the 'r' raw text input, made sure I have the most recent chromedriver version, added the localhost to the host file. I am running this on a Windows (work) machine. I just got home and ran an identical code (with modified path name) on my Apple machine, and got it to work no problem. Could it have anything to do with running the script on a networked machine?

Comment: So it's definitely something to do with running on a server. I copied the exact code and webdriver over to my desktop, disconnected from the VPN, ran the code on my own WIFI and it ran perfectly. Any ideas for how to circumvent being a on a corporate network? This is for a project at work, so it's kind of imperative that I'm on the network.

Answer (score 3):

Same error here. My issue was that I had `chromedriver.exe` on a company sharedrive.  Some firewall or security setting was presumably preventing python from accessing the executable file in that remote location.

I made `chromedriver.exe` local and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

While passing the *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver* binary through the argument **executable_path** you need to mention the *path* within single quotes (i.e. `''`) seperated by a single forward slash (i.e. `\`) along with the raw switch (i.e. `r`) as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'U:\Scraping\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
```

### Additional Consideration

- Ensure that you have downloaded the exact format of the *ChromeDriver* binary from the [download location](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.39/) pertaining to your underlying OS among:

  - **chromedriver_win32.zip**: For *Windows OS*
- Ensure that *ChromeDriver* binary have executable permission for the **non-administrator**  user.
- Execute your *Test* as a **non-administrator**  user.
- Another potential reason for the error can be due to missing the entry **`127.0.0.1 localhost`** in **`/etc/hosts`**

### Solution

- *Windows OS* - Add `127.0.0.1 localhost` to `/etc/hosts`
- *Mac OSX* - Ensure the following entries:

  ```
  127.0.0.1   localhost
  255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
  ::1 localhost
  fe80::1%lo0 localhost
  ```

### References

As per the discussion in [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service geckodriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2903):

- Selenium does not require `127.0.0.1 localhost` to be explicitly set in the host file.
- However it is mandatory requirement to map *localhost* to the ***IPv4 local loopback (127.0.0.1)***
- The mechanism of this mapping does not have to be through the hosts file always.
- On *Windows OS* systems it is not mapped in the hosts file at all (resolving localhost is done by the DNS resolver).

### TL;DR

[How to reset the Hosts file back to the default](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/972034/how-to-reset-the-hosts-file-back-to-the-default)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience to @rvictordelta. For some reason I could no longer edit the location where the driver was through python, and when I changed to a shared drive for work that wouldn't work as well. Finally, used this code below. This version is good because it checks for the most up to date chrome driver. If the driver exists it simply uses it, but if not it will download and install it.

```
custom_path=r'C:\Users\username'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(path=custom_path).install(),options=chrome_options))
```